# How to iteratively search and remove from a list when not using the standard library

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a simple loop without recursion to traverse through a Rust list (first node is a sentinel) and remove an element (not the sentinel) from it.

I've managed to successfully write a `remove_first` function that works on its own, but trying to iterate through the list is causing me issues with the borrow checker:

Here's the program:

```
// This code is placed in the public domain
struct Node<'a> {
    val : i32,
    next : Option<&'a mut Node<'a> >,
}
struct List<'a> {
    glob : Option<&'a mut Node<'a> >,
}


struct AllocatedList<'a> {
   el0 : Node<'a>,
   el1 : Node<'a>,
   el2 : Node<'a>,
   el3 : Node<'a>,
   el4 : Node<'a>,
   el5 : Node<'a>,
   el6 : Node<'a>,
   sentinel : Node<'a>,
   list : List<'a>,
}
  fn remove_cur<'a>(mut iter : &mut Option<&mut Node<'a> >) -> &'a mut Node<'a> {
      match *iter {
        Some(ref mut glob_next) => {
             let rest : Option<&'a mut Node <'a> >;
             match glob_next.next {
                 Some(ref mut root_cell) => {
                    rest = std::mem::replace(&mut root_cell.next, None);
                 },
                 None => rest = None,
             }
             match std::mem::replace(&mut glob_next.next, rest) {
                Some(mut root_cell) =>
                {
                   return root_cell;
                },
                None => panic!("Empty list"),
             }
        },
        None => panic!("List not initialized"),
     }
  }

impl<'a> List<'a> {
  fn remove_first(self : &mut List<'a>) -> &'a mut Node<'a> {
      return remove_cur(&mut self.glob);
  }

  fn remove_search(self : &mut List<'a>, searched:i32) -> &'a mut Node<'a> {
      let mut list_iter : &mut Option<&'a mut Node<'a> > = &mut self.glob;
      loop {
          match *list_iter {
              Some(ref mut cur_cell) => {
                match cur_cell.next {
                   Some(ref item) => {
                       if cur_cell.val == searched {
                            break;
                       }
                   },
                   None=>{},
                  }
                  list_iter = &mut cur_cell.next;
              },
              None => { // use whatever is available if nothing matches well
                  panic!("Not found");
              },
         }
    }
    return remove_cur(list_iter);
 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a : AllocatedList = AllocatedList{
        el0 : Node{val : 0, next : None},
        el1 : Node{val : 1, next : None},
        el2 : Node{val : 2, next : None},
        el3 : Node{val : 3, next : None},
        el4 : Node{val : 4, next : None},
        el5 : Node{val : 5, next : None},
        el6 : Node{val : 6, next : None},
        sentinel : Node {val : -1, next : None},
        list : List{glob:None},
    };
    a.el5.next = Some(&mut a.el6);
    a.el4.next = Some(&mut a.el5);
    a.el3.next = Some(&mut a.el4);
    a.el2.next = Some(&mut a.el3);
    a.el1.next = Some(&mut a.el2);
    a.el0.next = Some(&mut a.el1);
    a.sentinel.next = Some(&mut a.el0);
    a.list.glob = Some(&mut a.sentinel);
    let removed_el = a.list.remove_first();
    println!("Removed {:?}", removed_el.val);
    let removed_el = a.list.remove_first();
    println!("Removed {:?}", removed_el.val);

    let removed_x = a.list.remove_search(5);
    println!("Removed {:?}", removed_x.val);
}
```

And the error is:

```
52:36 error: cannot borrow `list_iter.0` as mutable more than once at a time [E0499]
          Some(ref mut cur_cell) => {
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
69:3 note: previous borrow ends here
     fn remove_search(self : &mut List<'a>, searched:i32) -> &'a mut Node<'a> {

61:49 error: cannot assign to `list_iter` because it is borrowed [E0506]
              list_iter = &mut cur_cell.next;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
52:36 note: borrow of `list_iter` occurs here
             Some(ref mut cur_cell) => {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there any recipe I can follow or any change I can make in my code (needs to work with nostdlib) to iterate through this list?

I'd rather not use recursion as it may get rather large in practice and I don't wish to overflow the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a recursive version working (pasted here for reference for others) but can someone help me convert it to be iterative: I'd rather not be limited by the stack size, if possible.

```
// This code is placed in the public domain
struct Node<'a> {
    val : i32,
    next : Option<&'a mut Node<'a> >,
}
struct List<'a> {
    glob : Option<&'a mut Node<'a> >,
}


struct AllocatedList<'a> {
   el0 : Node<'a>,
   el1 : Node<'a>,
   el2 : Node<'a>,
   el3 : Node<'a>,
   el4 : Node<'a>,
   el5 : Node<'a>,
   el6 : Node<'a>,
   el7 : Node<'a>,
   sentinel : Node<'a>,
   list : List<'a>,
}
  fn remove_cur<'a>(mut iter : &mut Option<&mut Node<'a> >) -> &'a mut Node<'a> {
      match *iter {
        Some(ref mut glob_next) => {
             let rest : Option<&'a mut Node <'a> >;
             match glob_next.next {
                 Some(ref mut root_cell) => {
                    rest = std::mem::replace(&mut root_cell.next, None);
                 },
                 None => rest = None,
             }
             match std::mem::replace(&mut glob_next.next, rest) {
                Some(mut root_cell) =>
                {
                   return root_cell;
                },
                None => panic!("Empty list"),
             }
        },
        None => panic!("List not initialized"),
     }
  }

  fn remove_search_recursive<'a> (mut node : &mut Option<&mut Node <'a> >, searched:i32) -> &'a mut Node<'a> {
    let mut found : bool = false;
    {
        match *node {
            Some(ref mut cur_cell) => {
                match cur_cell.next {
                    Some(ref item) => {
                        if item.val == searched {
                               found = true;
                        }
                    },
                    None => panic!("Not found"),
                 }
                 if !found {
                    return remove_search_recursive(&mut cur_cell.next, searched);
                 }
            },
            None => panic!("Not impl"),
        }
    }
    if found {
       return remove_cur(node);
    }
    panic!("Not impl");
 }

impl<'a> List<'a> {
  fn remove_first(self : &mut List<'a>) -> &'a mut Node<'a> {
      return remove_cur(&mut self.glob);
  }
  fn remove_search_recursive(self : &mut List<'a>, searched:i32) -> &'a mut Node<'a> {
     return remove_search_recursive(&mut self.glob, searched);
  }
}
fn main() {
    let mut a : AllocatedList = AllocatedList{
        el0 : Node{val : 0, next : None},
        el1 : Node{val : 1, next : None},
        el2 : Node{val : 2, next : None},
        el3 : Node{val : 3, next : None},
        el4 : Node{val : 4, next : None},
        el5 : Node{val : 5, next : None},
        el6 : Node{val : 6, next : None},
        el7 : Node{val : 7, next : None},
        sentinel : Node {val : -1, next : None},
        list : List{glob:None},
    };
    a.el6.next = Some(&mut a.el7);
    a.el5.next = Some(&mut a.el6);
    a.el4.next = Some(&mut a.el5);
    a.el3.next = Some(&mut a.el4);
    a.el2.next = Some(&mut a.el3);
    a.el1.next = Some(&mut a.el2);
    a.el0.next = Some(&mut a.el1);
    a.sentinel.next = Some(&mut a.el0);
    a.list.glob = Some(&mut a.sentinel);
    let removed_el = a.list.remove_first();
    println!("Removed {:?}", removed_el.val);
    let removed_el = a.list.remove_first();
    println!("Removed {:?}", removed_el.val);

    let removed_x = a.list.remove_search_recursive(5);
    println!("Removed {:?}", removed_x.val);
    let removed_y = a.list.remove_search_recursive(3);
    println!("Removed {:?}", removed_y.val);
}
```